# find an example which is not obtained by attaching a square root of an element of F?

Tags: field-theory

Give an example of a degree 2 extension K of a field F of characteristic
two which is not obtained by attaching a square root of
an element of F

my trial :i was  taking  $x^2-a$ = $0$  as $K=F(\sqrt a)$  as i don't know the next step ,,,Pliz help me as how to find the example

Comment: @THOMAS andrew  im not getting   can u elaborate in detail ???

Comment: Michael, did you already read the excellent answer from Pete L. Clark? There you find everything.